# VPC Interface Endpoint do you need for each Subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc-endpoint

According to AWS documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints.html
it has a private  IP address from the IP address range of the subnet.
So if for example, there are 2 subnets for example(private1, private2) and RDS is hosted in private 2. Does it mean a VPC end point need to be created for each subnet or it depends on where your for example Lamda is. For example, if Lamda's are hosted in a private1 subnet then you need only it on the private 1 subnet? However, for example if you access Query Editor for example from Console, as RDS is in private 2 subnet, do you need another VPC End Point in private 2.

Goal of this is to internalize traffic to AWS VPC.

Answer (score 3):

Reading further VPC endpoints  can span  across multiple availability zones in the same VPC. Hence, reading this, it should not matter which subnets you deploy as long as it is in the same VPC.